# Use TAB for auto completion on emacs doom

Tags: emacs

How can i use TAB key instead of enter key for auto complete on emacs doom?

I have tried setting values for ac-complete and also lsp-mode. But nothing seems to work?

Could someone advise as im new to emacs?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know emacs doom and I don't think I can give a simple answer but these are the steps I'd take to work it out and (possibly) do it:

1. Work out the actual name of the command you need and which is currently bound to Enter (RET) using  `M-h k RET`
2. Set the new binding with: `M-x local-set-key RET TAB RET name_of_command_from_1 RET`

If you then want to unbind the RET key: `M-x local-unset-key RET RET`

If you want to make this persistent you'll need to update your .emacs file. You'll need the name of the doom mode which can be found with `M-x m` (lets assume it's doom) and add something like the following to .emacs:

```
(add-hook 'doom-mode-hook
      (function (lambda ()
                      (local-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'name_of_command_from_1)

)) t)
```